# Calling a function from an angularjs controller using dynamically created HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to create a list of map markers for addresses returned by my API. I want the [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) to have a button that calls a function from the controller, but for some reason, `ng-click` isn't doing anything at all.

I've tried using `$compile`, but haven't had any luck. Here's what my controller looks like:

```
    drivingApp.controller('MapController', ['$resource', '$scope', '$window', '$http', '$compile', function($resource, $scope, $window, $http, $compile) {
    $scope.testPrint = function () {
        console.log('Test')
    };
    $scope.initMap = function () {
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('user-token'));
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + sessionStorage.getItem('user-token');
        $http.get('my_api_url') // Request currently available properties
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.allPropertyList = response.data; // Put server response in scope
                var mapCenter = {lat: 29.3568, lng: -98.494738}; // Center the map in the middle of the city

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: mapCenter,
                    zoom: 9
                });

                var marker, i;

                for (i = 0; i < $scope.allPropertyList.length; i++) {
                    // Get latitude and longitude for each property returned by the API
                    var latitude = parseFloat($scope.allPropertyList[i]['property_latitude']);
                    var longitude = parseFloat($scope.allPropertyList[i]['property_longitude']);
                    var property_address = $scope.allPropertyList[i]['property_address'];
                    /*
                    Create content for the info window of the map marker.
                    Allow the user to select properties from the map itself.
                    */

                    var contentString = '<h1 style="font-size: 18px">' + property_address + '</h1>'
                                        +'<div>'
                                        +'<a id="selectFromMapButton" ng-click="testPrint()" class="c-btn" style="color: white">Select Property</a>'
                                        +'</div>';
                    $compile(contentString)($scope);
                    createMarker(i);

                }

                function createMarker(i) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                    });


                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });
                }

            });
    };

}]);
```

I want to call `testPrint` by clicking on the info window of the map markers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So the info window opens fine, but the button in the info window isn't binding?

Comment: Could you add the `$compile` line(s) you tried?

Comment: @MisterMystery yes, the that is correct. Give me a moment and I'll show you the `$compile` line I tried.

Comment: @MisterMystery Edited my original post with the `$compile` line.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest you do ha. I'm sure you could do it using jQuery but I will try and think of another angular way.

Comment: @MisterMystery any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178216/discussion-between-mistermystery-and-vipertherapper).

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works. I changed some of the map logic in the `for` loop and removed the `createMarker` function for simplicity. You should be able to add it back in if you want.

```
for (i = 0; i < $scope.allPropertyList.length; i++) {
    // Get latitude and longitude for each property returned by the API
    var latitude = parseFloat($scope.allPropertyList[i]['property_latitude']);
    var longitude = parseFloat($scope.allPropertyList[i]['property_longitude']);
    var property_address = $scope.allPropertyList[i]['property_address'];
    /*
    Create content for the info window of the map marker.
    Allow the user to select properties from the map itself.
    */

    // Add the marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude , longitude),
        map: $scope.map
    });

    // Build the content string
    var contentString = '<h1 style="font-size: 18px">' + property_address + '</h1>'
                        +'<div>'
                        +'<a id="selectFromMapButton" ng-click="testPrint()" class="c-btn" style="color: white">Select Property</a>'
                        +'</div>';
    // Compile the contentString
    var compiledContent = $compile(contentString)($scope)

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ''
    });

    // Add the event listener and open info window.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, contentString, scope, infowindow) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(scope.map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, compiledContent[0], $scope, infowindow));
}
```

Comment: Nope. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined`.

Comment: I edited my answer. Note that I added the infowindow var back in and changed the event listener params

Comment: Now the markers don't show up, but I don't have an error in the console.

Comment: Try changing `var map = new google.maps.Map` to `$scope.map = new google.maps.Map`

Comment: That's what I did, and the markers do show up. However, `testPrint` is still not being called when I click on the button.

Comment: @vipertherapper I just fixed a typo, let me know if that fixes it.